# Stopping, snapshotting and restarting EBS server

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon EC2 and just pulled down some Unix based image (I think it was an IBM image). It launched fine, worked great and was able to be stopped and snapshotted, all through the console. However, when I replicated the snapshot and launched a new image, albeit of a smaller size, the new image came up with errors. Is there something I need to do before snapshotting an image to make it restartable?

Answer (score 0):

YOu should pause, the processes writing to the EBS volume, so that the EBS volume is in a consistent state.